# Creating modal with Backbone - passing variable to template

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I am trying to figure out if I can pass a variable to a template.

Here is the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="modal-template">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Team Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <% for(var i=0; i
            <XXX.length
                    ; i++) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href='/users/<%=user._id%>/teams/<%= teams[i]._id%>/teamDashboard'>
                            <%= XXX[i].teamName %>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</script>
```

I want to pass the above template a variable, let's say it's the variable identified above and below named XXX.

```
<script>

    $(function($) {

        var XXX = {};
        //how can I pass the template the variable XXX???

        var Modal = Backbone.Modal.extend({
            template: _.template($('#modal-template').html()),
            cancelEl: '.bbm-button'
        });
        $('.ImportTeamsFromTeamSnap').on('click', function(){
            var modalView = new Modal();
            $('.app').html(modalView.render().el);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically I want the template to render differently depending on the variable XXX. This could be a handlebars template, or any type of template that makes it possible.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's wrong with `html = compiled_template({ XXX: XXX })`? What am I missing?

Comment: thanks, I could try that, do you have a link to an example?

Comment: I haven't read the underscore documentation, but thanks for pointing me to that, it's going to be a fascinating read

Comment: hi at @muistooshort - I have noticed that you answer a few questions on Backbone and Underscore on SO. So I am a bit bemused why you didn't feel like answering this question to the best of your abilities. I haven't solved this question yet, I also have another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983468/underscore-templates-with-backbone-view that I could use your help with. Thanks.

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#template this didn't help much

Comment: Sorry but I only have a limited amount of time and I'm almost all server-side these days so I don't do much Backbone. You'll probably have to investigate how `Backbone.Model` works, there has to be a way to control what goes inside it, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Model to the modal. Something like this:

```
<script>

    $(function($) {

        var XXX = {};
        //how can I pass the template the variable XXX???

        var Modal = Backbone.Modal.extend({
            template: _.template($('#modal-template').html()),
            cancelEl: '.bbm-button'
        });
        $('.ImportTeamsFromTeamSnap').on('click', function(){
            var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extends({});

            var modalView = new Modal();
            modalView.model = new MyModel(XXX);
            $('.app').html(modalView.render().el);
        });
    });
</script>
```